# How do Tomcat's Cookies work?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I am confused about a couple things regarding cookies.

1. Why do I need to use/customize `javax.servlet.http.Cookie` class in order to implement a `Remember me` feature?

   In my `web.xml` couldn't I just use?:

   ```
   <session-config>
       <session-timeout>10080</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
   ```
2. Isn't it a security issue having cookies on a computer? Couldn't a cracker steal another user's cookie and hijack their session?

Comment: 1) You don't - you just need to create an [http session](http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/project5/session_tutorial.html). 2) Yes, this is called [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).

Comment: If you use a JSP then [they automatically create http sessions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_session_tracking.htm). Various other things can case sessions to be created also.

Comment: Yes. This is part of the [Java EE servlet spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't - you just need to create an [http session](http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/project5/session_tutorial.html). Tomcat will either create a cookie or use a `jsessionid` URL parameter to maintain your session - this is part of the [Java EE servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/). If you use a JSP then they [automatically create http sessions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_session_tracking.htm). Various other things can cause sessions to be created also.
2. Yes, this is called [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).